# ¿Como puedo hacer un "cast" a los datos que obtengo con context.Database.SqlQuery de c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Utilizo un **`context.Database.SqlQuery<T>()`** para obtener los datos del query de abajo, pero no logro  por ningun metodo mostrar esos datos en el frontend.

No encuentro la manera de "castear" a una clase llamada **`Resumen`**, la cual contiene todos los datos que extrae la consulta.

El error es:

> "No se puede convertir del tipo:
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List ''".

He intentado castear de todas las formas, incluso usé List Object para que no tenga problemas de tipo, pero obtengo el mismo error. Estaré muy agradecido por la ayuda de los que ya pasaron por esto.

```
string query = "SELECT " +
                   "A1.fecha," +

                    "cl.nombre as \"cliente_nombre\"," +
                    "tp.nombre as \"tipo_papel\"," +
                    "A1.GM2_NOM," +
                    "round(AVG(A1.T_LARGO_PROM_2X_BOB), 1) as \"T_LARGO\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.T_ANCHO_PROM_2X_BOB), 1) as \"T_ANCHO\", " +
                    "round(AVG((A1.FACTOR_LQ_LC + A1.FACTOR_LQ_LT) / 2), 1) as \"L_Q\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.GM2_PROM2), 1) as \"GM2_LAB\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.H_PORC_PLS), 1) as \"H_PLS\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.COBB_T_PROM_2X_BOB), 1) as \"COBB_T\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.COBB_CT_PROM_2X_BOB), 1) as \"COBB_CT\", " +
                    "round(AVG(A1.GURLEY_SEG_PROM), 1) as \"Gurley\" " +
                "FROM " +
                    "ADMIN2.LC_LAB A1 " +
                   " join lc_cli cl on cl.id = A1.CLIENTE_LC " +
                   " join lc_tip_pap tp on tp.id = A1.TIP_PAP_ID " +

               " GROUP BY " +
               "A1.fecha ," +
                   " cl.nombre, " +
                   " tp.nombre, " +
                    "A1.GM2_NOM," +
                    "A1.TIP_PAP_ID" +
                   " order by cl.nombre;";
List<Resumen> result = (List<Resumen>)context.Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(query);
```

A contnuación, el codigo del Modelo Resumen:

```
public class Resumen
{

    public string FECHA { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Cliente")]
    public string CLIENTE_NOMBRE { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Papel")]
    public string TIPO_PAPEL { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Gramaje")]
    public decimal GM2_NOM { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("T. Largo")]
    public decimal T_LARGO { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("T. Ancho")]
    public decimal T_ANCHO { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("L/Q")]
    public decimal L_Q { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("g/m2 Lab.")]
    public decimal GM2_LAB { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("H (%) PLS")]
    public decimal H_PORC_PLS { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("COBB T")]
    public decimal COBB_T_PROM_2X_BOB { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("COBB CT")]
    public decimal COBB_CT_PROM_2X_BOB { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Gurley")]
    public decimal GURLEY_SEG_PROM { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Hola, indica por favor el código de la clase Modelo `Resumen`.

Comment: Hola Rafael, ya agregué el código del modelo Resumen.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, no te va a funcionar un simple **cast** a `(List<Resumen>)`, ya que el método genérico `SqlQuery<Resumen>(query)` devuelve un objeto del tipo `DbRawSqlQuery<T>`.

Lo que debes hacer es transformar el resultado en un `List<Resumen>`, haciendo el **cast** ahí mismo:

El código sería así:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(query).ToList<Resumen>();
```

---

**UPDATE:** Según el autor de la pregunta, la solución que se ajusta a su desarrollo y resuelve el problema, es la siguiente:

```
List<Resumen> result = (List<Resumen>)context.Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Al proceder con la solución propuesta, me sale lo sgte.: Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(string, params, object[]) no estáticos. Comento que a mismo tiempo que escribo aquí, investigo como solucionar estos problemas. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @vrecalde: El error te da al compilar o en tiempo de ejecución ?

Comment: el error da en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Añado que he puesto de la sgte manera: List<Resumen> result = (List<Resumen>)context.Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(query).ToList();  De esta forma ya no me da error, pero en tiempo de ejecución me da el sgte error: 'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended' He investigado sobre ese error y en todos lados dice que se trata de un error en la sintaxis del query, pero realmente no veo el error, he seguido todos los consejos, pero nada funciona. La misma consulta funciona correctamente en Oracle.

Comment: Debo crear otro tópico para este error? Creo que el primer error fue solucionado gracias a tu consejo, este error que describo ahora ya está relacionado con la BD creo.

Comment: @vrecalde: Deberías crear otra pregunta. Y recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: @vrecalde: Lo que deberías hacer también es crear una respuesta con la ´solución que has encontrado. Por ejemplo lo que has escrito en los comentarios. Así quedará mas claro para la gente que consulte esta pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @rafael, he puesto de la sgte manera y el error quedo solucionado:  List<Resumen> result = (List<Resumen>)context.Database.SqlQuery<Resumen>(query).ToList();